# Matlab Parfor Variable cannot be Classified

Tags: matlab, parfor

Anyone have an idea why this isn't working? I'm trying to run a parfor loop. I can do the exact same code using a simple for loop, but I need to use this with the parfor for a massive dataset.

```
parfor n = [1:rows]

   MeanIV(n,1) = mean([LastIV(n,1); BidIV(n,1);AskIV(n,1)])

   if isnan(MeanIV(n)) == 1    
      SubIV = dated.IV(n)    
      MeanIV(n,1) = SubIV    
   else    
      MeanIV(n,1) = mean([LastIV(n,1); BidIV(n,1);AskIV(n,1)])    
   end 

   dated.MeanIV = double(MeanIV)

end
```

I get this error " The variable MeanIV in a parfor cannot be classified."

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_of7_-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely the line

```
dated.MeanIV = double(MeanIV)
```

that is the problem.

`parfor` will try to "slice" `MeanIV`, i.e. send individual rows to different workers. However, at the `dated` line, you need the entirety of the array.

Move the line after the `end` of the `parfor` loop, and it will work.